# SQL Server delete rows from large table and create indexes

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in a production server with 350 million rows and aproximatelly 25GB size. It has a single clustered identity index. 
The queries targeting this table require some missing indexes for better perfomance.
I need to delete unnecessary data (aprox 200 million rows) and then create two non-clustered indexes.
However, I have some concerns:

1. I need to avoid increasing the log too much
2. Keep the database downtime as low as possible.
3. Keep the identity (primary key) the same in the remaining data.

I would like to hear you opinion for the best solution to adopt.

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server are you using.  This can be done as an online operation in Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Sorry I missed that: SQL Server 2008r2 Standard Edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a guideline on how you might do this:

1. Suspend insert/update operations or start logging them explicitly (this might result in degraded performance).
2. Select the records to keep into a new table.

Then you have two options.  If this is the only table in your universe:

3. Build the indexes on the new table.
4. Stop the system.
5. Rename the existing table to something else.
6. Rename the new table to the real table name
7. Turn the system back on.

If there are other tables (such as foreign key relationships):

3. Truncate the existing table
4. Insert the data into the existing table
5. Build the secondary indexes
6. Turn the system back on

Depending on your user requirements, one of the above variations is likely to work for your problem.

Note that there are other more internally intensive techniques.  For instance, create a replicated database and once that is working, you have two systems and can do the clean-up work on one at a time (a method such as this would be the preferred method for a system with near 100% uptime requirements).  Or create a separate table that is just right and swap the table spaces.

Comment: Well, yes it seems a good aproach, the only thing I had to think about is the time it would take to copy the recorts to keep into  a new table (aproximatelly 100 million rows / 9GB) and then creating the indexes. I know that I shouldnt but, would it be faster if I copy the data after the creating the indexes?

Comment: @nunopacheco, if your database is in the `SIMPLE` or `BULK_LOGGED` recovery model, an INSERT...SELECT into a table with only the clustered index is minimally logged when you specify the `TABLOCK` hint.  See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070%28v=sql.100%29.aspx.  Create non-clustered indexes afterward.

Comment: @nunopacheco . . . Usually it is faster to copy data and then create the indexes.

Comment: @DanGuzman, the database is is a Full recovery model. So, the insert of 100 milion rows will increase the log. After it, when creating the indexes the log will grow also, yes? I have to ensure that there is enough disk space...

Comment: Another thing: Should I be aware of tempdb too?

Comment: All operations are fully logged in the `FULL` recovery model.  Consider temporarily changing it to `BULK_LOGGED` during the maintenance to take advantage of minimal logging and change it back to `FULL` afterwards.  Tempdb shouldn't be a consideration unless you specify the `SORT_IN_TEMPDB` option for index creation.

Comment: @DanGuzman, I dont have permission in this server for doing that, but I will discuss it with the administrators for sure. Thank you!

Comment: @GordonLinoff, one question: what do you mean in the first option the points 4 and 7 (stop and start the system?) you mean stop the insert/update operations or stop and restart server?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: What do you think about just delete unnecessary rows and then create indexes?

Comment: @nunopacheco, if `BULK_LOGGED` isn't an option, you could delete in batches by clustered index key ranges as an online operation if your batches are small and transaction log backups are scheduled frequently to avoid log grrowth. Then, during a maintenance window, create one index, backup the log, create the second index, and backup the log again. This will take longer overall but reduce downtime.  However, you might get deadlocks during the delete due to concurrent activity.

Comment: @nunopacheco . . . In general, deleting large numbers of rows is more expensive than just re-creating the table.  However, you could do this over time, but it would take a long time.

Comment: Thank you all. @GordonLinoff: I will follow the first option.